# Set data from database to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, listbox

I have database in Azure and I created table:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2VGT.png)
I send data from column 'Category' to listbox1 and I want send data to listbox2 from 'Type' table, where element 'Category' is the same as the selected item in a listbox1. For example: when in listbox1 is selected 'Food', listbox2 displays 'Fruit'.
I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
  private async void ViewType(string cat)      
{
       MobileServiceCollection<string, string> result = null;
        MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exception = null;
        try
        {
        result = await todoTable.Where(TodoItem => TodoItem.Category == cat)
                .Select(todoItem => todoItem.Type)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }

        if (exception != null)
        {
            await new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Error loading items").ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            ListBox2.ItemsSource = result.Distinct(); 
        }
    }

 private void ListBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string _category = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        ViewType(_category);
    }
```

Anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: Don't you want an event for ListBox1 selection changed?

Comment: Problem solved. ViewType(_category); should be in Listbox1